# Как сделать адаптивную высоту блоков?

Tags: html, css

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, как адаптировать высоту под ширину? Если менять разрешение, то между элементами в блоке появляются огромные паддинги или же вообще наезжают друг на друга. Как это можно решить? И помогает ли в таком случае функция calc?

Answer (score 0):

Можно указать отступ в `rem`, он будет расчитвать относительно размера шрифта (а размер шрифта то при адаптации вы меняете).

Так же можно использовать bootstrap v4.1. Там есть классы типо `pb-md-3`, `pb-sm-3`, `pb-3`.